# Using -Dspring.config.name and -Dspring.config.location in gradle test command line

Tags: spring, testing, gradle, spring-boot

I am able to use `-Dspring.config.name` and `-Dspring.config.location` in my Spring Boot application successfully. And now want to use same `-Dspring.config.location` to pass to Gradle test task. It seems to be not working for me. Although I can pass other system property and use in my test classes.

I want to use this to run my tests in different environment. I know that Spring profile can be used.

any help would be appreciated

Edit: using `-Dspring.config.name=app-test` and/or `-Dspring.config.location=classpath:/conf/app-test.properties` not being picked-up up by spring to load property file. but in spring boot it is perfectly working.

mentioning of *I can pass other system property and use in my test classes*. meaning there is no issue in gradle to pass system property to junit test context

Comment: What does it mean: *It seems to be not working for me.*?

Comment: I think you also need to be explicit about the command that you used (it doesn't make any sense that you can set one system property but not another, unless they are actually different in context).

Answer (score 5):

-Dspring.config.location maybe wrong.
If you run jar file from command line, would you try

```
$ java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.location=classpath:app-test.properties
```

Or you can set in test class:

```
@TestPropertySource(locations = "classpath:app-test.properties")
public class TestClass1{...}
```

I hope this help!

References: https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html