# How can I dynamically use externalized properties file with Spring jar?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

With this setup (from Eclipse using Windows10)

[image]
[image]

I was able to correctly start my SpringBoot application. This one worked too (same directory pattern):

[image]

Now I'm packaging my project as JAR and I want to use an external properties file. I had an `teste32.yml` file beside my JAR at the same directory (also tried to use it inside `/config` directory, as show [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/htmlsingle/#boot-features-external-config), but it didn't work either)

I want to dynamically use a properties file beside my JAR file everytime. Doesn't matter at which directory they are, I wanted to dynamically point to a properties file always at the same directory as the JAR is. I want to say to my client: "take this JAR and this file, put them wherever you want and run this command X and everything will be alright". I'm trying to discover command X but before I add some dynamic path, I'm trying with absolutes paths. I'm using this:

```
java -jar myJar.jar -Dspring.config.name=teste32 -Dspring.config.location=C:\workspace\myProject\target\
```

I manually copied `teste32` inside `target\` to test this. But this didn't work. This didn't work either (only `spring.config.location` variants):

```
-Dspring.config.location=file:C:\workspace\myProject\target\
-Dspring.config.location=classpath:/
-Dspring.config.location=file:C:/workspace/myProject/target/
I also tried with no spring.config.location, only name
```

So my questions are:

1. What does `classpath:` and `file:` mean? Until now I got the 2 correct setups by pure luck and I would like to understand when to use them.
2. When I have my project package as a JAR, what `classpath` becomes?
3. Finally, which combination is necessary to dynamically use a properties always at the same directory as the JAR?

**UPDATE**
Using `--debug` at the correct example got me this line at the very begging (Spring banner was still visible):

```
2018-09-25 15:45:14.480 DEBUG 11360 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.c.ConfigFileApplicationListener  : Loaded config file 'file:src/main/resources/xirulei/teste32.yml' (file:src/main/resources/xirulei/teste32.yml)
```

But after moving `myJar.jar` and `teste32.yml` to a specific directory and running `java -jar myJar.jar -Dspring.config.name=teste32 --debug` (without spring.config.location, since `teste32` is at the same directory as JAR), I simply didn't get any `ConfigFileApplicationListener` debug line.

Answer (score 0):

a) `java -jar myJar.jar -Dspring.config.name=teste32 -Dspring.config.location=C:\workspace\myProject\target`

Did you check content of `target` dir? I'm pretty sure your cfg file is placed to `target\classes\xirulei` and it is why Spring cannot find it in `target`

b) When you place `teste32.yml` in the same directory as jar file then Spring must be able to find it (given this directory is working directory) without `-Dspring.config.location` (but you still need to provide `-Dspring.config.name=teste32`)

c) When you use `-jar` and do not provide additional class paths then `classpath:` points to the root of packages inside jar. Spring cannot find your file at `classpath:/` because your file is at `classpath:/xirulei/`

Comment: I manually added `teste32.yml` file at `C:\workspace\myProject\target` after building my jar with `mvn clean install`, sorry if I missed that information. But as you said a copy indeed existed at target\classes\xirulei.

Comment: I just tried without `spring.config.location` but it didn't work. What do you mean by 'given this directory is working directory' ?

Comment: *Oh, formatting in comments is broken :(*

Let says there is `/abc/xyz/myprj.jar`

I can do

`cd abc; java -jar xyz/myprj.jar`

In this case working dir will be `abc` - i.e. jar dir and working dir are different

If I do

`cd abc/xyz; java -jar myprj.jar`

Then working dir is the same as jar dir

Comment: So you should `cd target` (or wherever  Maven puts jar file) before calling `java`

Comment: Another question - did you provide exact command you called or "simplified" it?

Comment: Ow...I did it, but it still didn't work. From inside target directory I tried `java -jar myJar.jar -Dspring.config.name=teste32` with a `teste32.yml` at root level inside target.

Comment: Well, you did right thing. Why do you think Spring does not pickup it?

Comment: I have a module project with 4 modules and all this is about `boot` module. So all my paths are actually /myProject/boot/target/

Comment: Add `--debug` to command line - Spring will print what it is using

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/180754/discussion-between-gabrielrado-and-alexander-pavlov).

Answer (score 0):

Well, after all it was a simple mistake. As [documentation says](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html) and as already pointed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45204361/3026886), it should be

```
java -jar myproject.jar --spring.config.name=myproject
```

and not

```
java - jar myproject.jar -Dspring.config.name=myproject
```

As stated on question, only when using Eclipse `-D`(JVM argument) is necessary. When using bash/cmd, just `--`(program argument) is the correct option:

[image]